# PHP Fatal error: Cannot access parent:: when current class scope has no parent in cakephp 3.x

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I have found the above issue in cakephp 3.x.

```
namespace App\Controller;

class UsersController extends AppController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $users = $this->Users->find('all');
        print_r($users); // <-- print_r creates a problem in cakephp 3.x
        $this->set('users', $users);
    }
}
```

And i have run this above code and i found the following error:

```
Error: Cannot access parent:: when current class scope has no parent
File /var/www/html/cakephp-3-1-5/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/Query.php
Line: 1018
```

This error comes because of print_r. I have also tried pr, var_dump but same issue exist.

And then after commenting print_r, it shut down apache and displays "The connection was reset" and then i need to restart my apache service and after that it works proper.

So the problem with this is i think print_r. But i don't know what actually problem is because as a developer i need to debug my resultset. And here it restrict me to use print_r, pr and var_dump.

My purpose is to display resultset.

Resultset

```
(int) 0 => object(Cake\ORM\Entity) {

    'id' => (int) 1,
    'title' => 'Distance between two addresses using Google Maps API and PHP',
    'description' => 'Calculate distance between two addresses........',
    'created' => object(Cake\I18n\Time) {

        'time' => '2015-11-30T11:50:21+0000',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'fixedNowTime' => false

    },
    'modified' => object(Cake\I18n\Time) {

        'time' => '2015-12-01T06:32:17+0000',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'fixedNowTime' => false

    },
    'status' => true,
    '[new]' => false,
    '[accessible]' => [
        '*' => true
    ],
    '[dirty]' => [],
    '[original]' => [],
    '[virtual]' => [],
    '[errors]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'Posts'

},
(int) 1 => object(Cake\ORM\Entity) {

    'id' => (int) 2,
    'title' => 'Ajax Pagination in CodeIgniter Framework',
    'description' => 'CodeIgniter have the pagination library by........',
    'created' => object(Cake\I18n\Time) {

        'time' => '2015-11-30T11:50:21+0000',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'fixedNowTime' => false

    },
    'modified' => object(Cake\I18n\Time) {

        'time' => '2015-11-30T11:50:21+0000',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'fixedNowTime' => false

    },
    'status' => true,
    '[new]' => false,
    '[accessible]' => [
        '*' => true
    ],
    '[dirty]' => [],
    '[original]' => [],
    '[virtual]' => [],
    '[errors]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'Posts'

}
```

Is it problem in cakephp 3.x?
Is cakephp 3.x stable release? 
And can i used it as development framework or go with previous version like 2.x?

Thanks.

Comment: you have to provide user object code to find a solution of your problem

Comment: **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/4808**

Comment: After doing some of the research, i have found that there is some Segmentation fault in cakephp 3.x till now. So we can use pj($var) or debug($var) in place of print_r(), pr().

Thanks for your approach.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some of the research, i have found that there is some Segmentation fault in cakephp 3.x till now. So we can use `pj($var)` or `debug($var)` in place of `print_r(), pr()`.

Thanks for your approach.